# java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'text' on null object

Tags: java, groovy

I am trying to read a file. The file is in the same folder as the class file. Below is my code:

```
class TestClass {

 static void readFile(String fileName) {
    // input stream
    def text =  TestClass.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(fileName).text;
    def lines = text.split('\n')
    print(lines);
  }

  public static void main(args) {
  readFile('abc.txt');
  }
}
```

However I get java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'text' on null object.

Answer (score 1):

To read a resource that is in the same package as the class, use `Class.getReourceAsStream()`. Reading it with the classloader looks it up at the root of the package tree (in the default package):

```
TestClass.class.getResourceAsStream(fileName)
```

Comment: Thank you. That did solve the issue. But when I try to read a file from different package with absolute file name using def text = GridSearchTest.class.classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/Users/xyz/src/test/resources/abc.txt").text. I get same error.

Comment: The ClassLoader can't be used to load an aritrary file on the file system. It can only load resources that are in the classpath, using a path starting at the default package. It's used to load resources bundles with the classes of the application. To load an arbitrary file, use File IO.

Comment: Is that applicable to the file in the same project?

Comment: At runtime, projects are irrelevant. Directories and jars are in the classpath, or they're not.